# How to get mail sent successfully with MailKit IMap?

Tags: c#, mailkit

I'd like to know if my outbox mail has been sent successfully..

```
var client = new ImapClient();
....
var folders = client.GetFolders(client.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
var folder = client.GetFolder("已发送");//get sent mail floder in Chinese
var folderAccess = folder.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
string path = @"C:\temp\";

for (int i = folder.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   var message = folder.GetMessage(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't send messages via IMAP, you can only send them via SMTP.

Sending messages via SMTP do not put them into any IMAP folder. You have to put them there yourself.

Comment: we can get mails that had recently been sent via SMTP.we can't get all of the mails that had sent via SMTP.I want to get the information about the message has been sent successfully..I would like to know if the other party received the message

Comment: That's not a feature that IMAP supports.

Comment: What you want is SMTP delivery status notifications: http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient_GetDeliveryStatusNotifications.htm

Comment: Not all SMTP servers support this feature, however, so there is no guarantee that you will actually receive them. Then, once you receive a status notification which will come as an email with a Content-Type of multipart/report with a child part of message/delivery-status: http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MessageDeliveryStatus.htm